# C++ Programming Homework Assignment (do...while loops)

Tags: c++

One of my programming assignments is as follows:

> The population of a town A is less than the population of town B. However, the population of town A is growing faster than the population of town B. Write a program that prompts the user to enter the population and growth rate of each town. The program outputs after how many years the population of town A will be greater than or equal to the population of town B and the populations of both the towns at that time. (A sample input is: Population of town A = 5000, growth rate of town A = 4%, population of town B = 8000, and growth rate of town B = 2%.)

I have the main part of the assignment down, input the population and growth rate and calculate the population after x years, but I can't figure out how to compare the final population of town A with the final population of town B and the combined total. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int popA, popB, year = 1; 
    double growth_rateA, growth_rateB; 

    cout << "Enter the population and growth rate of Town A: ";
    cin >> popA >> growth_rateA;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the population and growth rate of Town B: ";
    cin >> popB >> growth_rateB;
    cout << endl;

    if (popA < popB && growth_rateA > growth_rateB)
    {
        {   
        do {
                (popA = ((growth_rateA / 100) * popA) + popA); // calculates population growth in one year
                (popB = ((growth_rateB / 100) * popB) + popB);
                year++;
            }

            while (popA < popB);

            cout << "Town A will surpass Town B in population after " << year << " years.\n" << endl;
            cout << "The final population of Town A is: " << popA << ".\n" << endl;
            cout << "The final population of Town B is: " << popB << ".\n" << endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid Data.";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you've already answered the question. What further comparisons do you need to make?

Comment: When you exit the do-while loop, your `popA` and `popB` variables will retain the value assigned to them in the last iteration of the loop. This means they will hold the "final" population count, in which `popA` is greater or equal than `popB`. Therefore, your code already does what's described in the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bettorun said it: because `popA` and `popB` were declared *outside* the `do`-`while` loop, they will retain their final values after you’ve exited that loop, and you can use them to perform other calculations on them.

Here’s your code with my addition. I also got rid of one level of nesting that wasn’t necessary and start the year at `0` instead of `1`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int popA, popB, year = 0; 
    double growth_rateA, growth_rateB; 

    cout << "Enter the population and growth rate of Town A: ";
    cin >> popA >> growth_rateA;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the population and growth rate of Town B: ";
    cin >> popB >> growth_rateB;
    cout << endl;

    if (popA < popB && growth_rateA > growth_rateB) {       
        do {
            (popA = ((growth_rateA / 100) * popA) + popA); // calculates population growth in one year
            (popB = ((growth_rateB / 100) * popB) + popB);
            year++;
        } while (popA < popB);

        int popDifference = popA - popB;
        int popTotal = popA + popB;
        cout << "Town A will surpass Town B in population after " << year << " years.\n" ;
        cout << "The final population of Town A is: " << popA << ".\n";
        cout << "The final population of Town B is: " << popB << ".\n";
        cout << "In year " << year << ", Town A has " << popDifference << " more people than town B.\n";
        cout << "The total population of both Town A and Town B is " << popTotal << ".\n";
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid Data.";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int popA, popB, year; 
double growA, growB;


 cout << "Population of town A ";
 cin >> popA;

  cout << "Population of town B ";
  cin >> popB;
// You can also say cout << "Population of town A and B "; and then say 
// cin >> popA >> popb; just to compile it better
cout << "Growth rate in percent of town A ";
cin >> growA;

cout << "growth rate in percent of town B ";
cin >> growB;
year = 0;
if (popA <= popB && growA > growB) 
{
   do {      
 (popA = ((growA / 100) * popA) + popA);
 (popB = ((growB / 100) * popB) + popB);
    year++;
   } while (popA <= popB);

      cout << year << " year(s) till Town A surpasses Town B in population ";
      cout << popA << ": population of Town A after it surpasses Town B";
      cout << popB << ": population of Town B after it is surpassed by Town A";
   }
   else
   {
       cout << "Does Not Compute";
   {
   cout << endl;
    }  
 }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers are discouraged because it is often difficult to see the specific change or answer that you have made that solves the problem. A bit of explanation will make your answer much easier and faster for users.